# how to translate a cmd line to a os.system line?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, os.system, configuration-files

I used to run a program called vina through the cmd line using the following command:

```
"\Program Files (x86)\The Scripps Research Institute\Vina\vina.exe" --config conf.txt --log log.txt
```

So, the program takes the config file to run and outputs a log file with the results. I am running the program in python using the os.system module. However, I can't assign the config file or the log file as I did in the cmd. I tried something like this in python:

```
os.system('C:/Program Files (x86)/The Scripps Research Institute/Vina/vina.exe' --config conf.txt --log log.txt)
```

The program opens real quick then closes, maybe because it doesn't run the config file. I have also tried putting the config into a string as follows (I am omiting the log thing until I get the config to work):

os.system('C:/Program Files (x86)/The Scripps Research Institute/Vina/vina.exe', '--config conf.txt')

In this case I get the error:

> TypeError: system() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Any ideas on how to specify the config file and the log file output in python lines as I do in cmd?

Comment: How about using os.path and extracting the path and then converting it to string to use with OS. System

Comment: Try `subprocess.call(['C:/Program Files (x86)/The Scripps Research Institute/Vina/vina.exe', '--config', os.path.normpath('C:/absolute/path/to/conf.txt'), '--log', 'log.txt'])`. This will probably try to create the log file in the working directory, which may be wrong. In that case pass the absolute path of the log file, creating it somewhere appropriate such as the user's `%TEMP%` directory via the `tempfile` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to replicate the command line command would be

```
os.system('"C:/Program Files (x86)/The Scripps Research Institute/Vina/vina.exe" --config conf.txt --log log.txt')
```

If that doesn't work, try specifying full paths for conf.txt and log.txt

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

os.system(r'"C:/Program Files (x86)/The Scripps Research Institute/Vina/vina.exe" --config conf.txt --log log.txt')